# Fourier transform of $C^\infty_0$, smooth functions vanishing at infinity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

Is there a proper description of the space $$\{\hat f\ | \ f\in C^\infty \ s.t. \forall \alpha\in\mathbb{N}^n,\forall \epsilon>0\exists K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\ K\ \text{compact};\ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash K}|\partial^\alpha_x f(x)|< \epsilon\}$$Especially I'm interested in the order of these distributions and their decay properties.

To be precise are there constants $C_{K,m}$, for every $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ compact and $m\in\mathbb{R}$, s.t.
$$\left|\int \hat f(\xi)\phi(\xi-b)\ d \xi\right|\leq C_{K,m}(1+b^2)^{-m}\|\phi\|_{\infty}\quad \forall\phi\in C_c(K)$$
or anything slightly worse?

Edit: The assertion automatically holds for all $m\in\mathbb{R}$ as long as it holds for any $m_0\in\mathbb{R}$, since all derivatives are again of the same form. This maximally exploits smoothness, so to establish this starting estimate or to give a counterexample, it is no loss assuming only $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Further the condition vanishing at infinity must be exploited, since on $C^\infty_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the assertion does not hold! (e.g. for $\Theta$ the Heaviside step function and $\phi$ some Schwartz-function $\widehat{\phi\ast\Theta}(\xi)=\hat\phi\cdot 1/2(\delta(\xi)-\text{p.v.}\frac{i}{\pi \xi})$ is of order 1)

Comment: I'm far from an expert here, but this space looks very close to (if not the same as) the Schwartz space of rapidly decreasing functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space

Comment: @StefanBehrens No, functions of the Schwartz space decay (together with all derivatives) much faster.

Comment: The space you describe is called $\dot{\mathscr B}$ in Laurent Schwartz' *Theorie des Distributions* (page 199).

Comment: it says that for every $\alpha$, $\partial_x^\alpha f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$, taking the FT, It means that $ \hat{f}$ is rapidly decreasing (for example $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{(n+1)/2}}, \hat{f}(\xi) = e^{-2\pi |\xi|}$)

Comment: @user1952009 What do you mean precisely? I think that such an $f$ need not be $L^1$ so that $\hat{f}$ a priory is only a tempered distribution. The first thing to do would be to determine the order.

Comment: The Theorem of Bochner gives a one-one characterization of FT's of (positive) measures in terms of continous [positive semidefinite functions](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positiv_semidefinite_Funktion). This should be somehow related, since a there we only miss the signs. We thus need to know how many properties of semidefinite functions hold also in the vector space they span (closed under their corresponding measure norm) and not only in their cone.